# ASP.NET Do something when time expires

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one very strange situation here.
I would like to know how can I know if time on my exam has expired. I need to do some processing, but I am unable to figure out how can I know when time is set to 0:00:00 do something. I have made that my time is ticking in Session from 0:01:00 to 0:00:00. I am working on ASP.NET application for the record.

Answer (score 1):

Since the server only executes code on page requests, you have no mechanism on the server side to do anything based on a timer.

The best way to handle this is to have a client side timer that tracks the used time in JavaScript. On expire have the form submit and show any applicable messages.

You can also do a server side timestamp in the session to make sure no one hacks/bypasses the client side code.

Comment: OK, great. Can you show me some example regarding this matter? I was thinking to call some function which will count a time from 0:01:00 to 0:00:00 once a user press button via <asp:Button OnClientClick="function" runat="server" /> . Now how can I make in JS to initiate some function made in asp.net after time runs out?

Comment: var availableseconds = 60; var timer = setInterval(function() {  updateTimer(--available seconds); }, 1000)

Will get you regular callbacks and you can make a function named updateTimer that updates your ui. When the passed in value = 0 have the function click a submit button which gives you a server side postback